# Fallout Shelter no longer seems to be dropping legendary items in the wasteland?

Tags: ios, fallout-shelter

After installing the first patch, followers sent to the wasteland have yet to return any legendary (yellow) items.

Previously my followers would return 1-3 items on each run.

Can anyone else confirm this behavior, or better yet explain what I need to do to get my explorers finding legendary items again.

Answer (score 4):

It is still possible to get legendary items, however, the chance is low. You wil most likely hit the 100 item limit before getting a legendary item.
Looking at the game code for Android:

```
num = (timeForCertainSuccess * 60 * Random) / TimeExplored;
ItemRarity itemRarity = Normal;
if (num < 0.1)
  itemRarity = Legendary;
else if (num < 0.2)
  eitemRarity = EItemRarity.Rare;
```

The item chance is based on some modifier * 60 * random value, all divided by the total time the dweller has explored. If the chance value is less than 0.1, then the item will be legendary.

Comment: +1 for the source code, but could you provide a link to the source?

Comment: It's not hosted online, I decompiled the apk and had a look at the code using JetBrains' dotPeek.

Comment: This has been my experience as well. I always hit the item cap way before the odds turn in my favor. I'm thinking about dropping some stats on my explorers to keep them out longer.

Answer (score 0):

> Well the game's wiki specifies that the longer your dweller explores
>   the Wasteland, the greater the chance to find special and legendary
>   items.

I haven't played the game before the patch (1.1) so I don't know how it was before and now it's a small chance, yeah, but not impossible... **in the last 5-6 days I found 4 legendary items**... I have a dweller exploring the Wasteland for 2 and half days, he found 2 items and 2 other dwellers exploring it for 1 day and a bit and they found 1 each. So it's not impossible but as I see it, it **only happens when your dweller is out there for more than a full day**.

Comment: I'm currently at 4 and 5 days continuous searching with no legendary items (yellow quality). Blue quality items are easily found after about a day and a half.

Comment: It may be that my dwellers are hitting 100 items (seems to be the maximum) in the wasteland very quickly because they have max stats.