# How am I supposed to combat the increased difficulty of incidents late-game in Fallout Shelter?

Tags: fallout-shelter

Okay, so this is getting irritating.

Early on in Fallout Shelter, I had the occasional incident from rushing, or just at random - and nine times out of ten I'd handle it without much of a problem. At that point in the game, I had probably half of my dwellers equipped with weapons, and most of them were somewhere just shy of level twenty.

NOW, with a vault at 200 dwellers, everyone equipped with a gun ( almost entirely sawed-off shotguns or better ), and a large number of level fifty dwellers - the incidents are becoming downright absurd.

I just watched five of six dwellers die, with a Mr. Handy assisting them, to an infestation of five roaches.

Now - this is all fine and dandy if you're constantly watching your vault and hitting people with stimpacks as they dwindle, but letting the game run at work and glancing down at my phone every few minutes, this can become a serious problem. One, single-room infestation, turns into five rooms with 90 roaches swarming everything that moves - all because I didn't catch it in time, and my armed, 5-stat, level 50 dwellers couldn't hang...

I'm getting a little frustrated having to revive tens of dwellers twice a day because I looked away too long. What's the deal Bethesda!? Shouldn't I have a LITTLE better chance than that!?

I mean, Deathclaws don't even inflict any casualties anymore, and they don't even clear my first floor - but roaches? A fire? Best break out the stimpacks! Molerats!? Don't get me started! Fifteen shots with the shotgun...

Comment: Molerats literally just devastated two full floors... Thirty dwellers down

Comment: That's a sick ass joke Bethesda... But don't worry! I wasn't saving those caps!

Comment: Let me correct myself -- two and a half floors*

Comment: Explore and have better weapons than sawed shotguns and armor.
Anyway, if it was an easy game (at least since the latest update) it would not be fun.

Comment: don't leave the game running while you're not paying attention to it.  There's really no reason, as the game progresses at real time regardless of whether it's open or not.  This is doubly true on hard mode - where every encounter is hard and death is permanent.

Answer (score 6):

Try to avoid upgrading rooms. Incidents are much worse in fully upgraded rooms than a room with hasn't been upgraded. In particular training rooms don't benefit much from upgrades so I don't bother to upgrade those rooms. I also don't upgrade medical and science rooms, so I can rush them over and over as necessary to generate stimpacks/radaways or to get rushing or incident related objectives. Most of the time I leave these later rooms occupied by a single dweller, and that's enough to deal with any incidents.

The only rooms I do upgrade are the energy/water/food resource production rooms. For example I have fully upgraded a Nuka-Cola bottling plant next to the vault door, and the dwellers there are armed to the teeth. I also make sure that any production room that I have upgraded is fully staffed. I don't bother to try to respond to incidents by moving people around. It never works well. (Though early in the game I did move weapons around. One missile launcher can make a big difference.)

You should also consider your vault layout. Storage and residential rooms should be left unoccupied and placed so incidents in them can't spread to other rooms, or at the very least only to one fully occupied room.

I've also limited the population of my vault to about 110, as there doesn't seem to be much point in going beyond that. It's already pain to deal that many dwellers. I'm not sure if vault population factors into the severity of incidents, but that might be something to consider. I don't seem to have as much of a problem with incidents as you do even in my fully upgraded rooms, but that could be because my dwellers have better weapons than yours. I'm currently tossing away anything that doesn't do least 10 damage on average. At the very least reducing the population of your vault would let increase the damage of the weapons the remaining dwellers are equipped with.

Finally, I'd recommend just putting your phone in your pocket when you can't pay close enough attention to respond to incidents. Unless you're actively grinding certain objectives, you might as well just leave the game alone. You can't have any incidents while you're not playing the game.

Comment: A couple of valid points; a couple that I'm not so enthused about too. I'm coming up on the final stretch of upgrading every room in my vault to max - with only my Nuka-Cola and my Nuke Reactors remaining. The biggest impacts seem to be in the training areas that you so aptly mentioned - so I might have to rebuild my bottom seven stories... Again. Thanks for the input though, I guess some of it is worth a try.

Comment: And BTW - How are you landing weapons that good? I get piles and piles of shotguns, with a Few special weapons out of lunchboxes ( enough to equip my first floor ), but that's about it...

Comment: @DigitalJedi805 I've never had a weapon problem with a battery of 18 maxed dwellers constantly exploring the wastes. Of course, my incidents aren't anywhere close what you describe.

Comment: Well I'll have to finish maxing out my exploration team then - it seems to be a necessity for anything worthwhile out of the wastes. Be glad you aren't dealing with the incidents I am @Dallium - I'm something like 15k caps in the hole after one missed molerat problem.

Comment: @DigitalJedi805 I usually have 24 dwellers out exploring, mostly level 50, but not max stats. Stats don't seem to make much difference, you hit the 100 item cap before you find legendary "gold" items. So they bring back a few blue items each trip, along with a bunch of junk that I try apply to item related objectives.

Comment: @DigitalJedi805 The longer your dwellers are out in the wastes, the odds of them finding rare and legendary items goes up. There's also events at certain time marks where they have a chance to get rare/legendary loot as well. One of my dwellers only has max strength, with a +7 endurance outfit can last out in the wastes with 25 stim packs and 15 radaways for almost three days before I have to recall him. He averages close to seven or eight rares.

Comment: @Trasiva I don't think it's possible to get legendary loot in the wasteland any more. I have dwellers out past the 4 day mark, but they always hit the 100 item cap before getting any legendary items. There is a bug though that can net you a legendary item right off the mark though.  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/232497/fallout-shelter-no-longer-seems-to-be-dropping-legendary-items-in-the-wasteland  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/232574/is-this-a-bug-or-is-it-luck

Comment: @RossRidge Well, if you hit the 60 hour mark and succeed the National Guard Depot depot, you get a legendary drop reward still. I know this only because that's how I've gotten three of my rusty missile launchers, an alien blaster, and my +7 endurance waste suit in the last two weeks. However, you're right on the regards of just FINDING legendaries in the wild, your odds are always low and more likely to fill your inventory with rares instead.

Comment: @Trasiva I haven't gotten anything better than rares (blue) from the National Guard Depot and I must've had a hundred explorers through it over the last two weeks. I've gotten one legendary item from the glitch, all the rest I have came from lunchboxes.

Comment: @RossRidge That's just bad luck on your part. It's not 100% chance, and I should have elaborated on it. I'd say the chance is about one in ten you'll actually get the legendary. I'd lock your dwellers in a room with some radroaches for a while as punishment, that should educate 'em and encourage better behavior.

Comment: @Trasiva The difference between your experience and mine suggests it's more than just luck. My dwellers routinely pass the three day mark exploring and have for weeks. My chance of getting a legendary from the NG Depot appears to be significantly less than 1%.  There's likely some other factor involved here.

Comment: @RossRidge Are you using trained dwellers? Mine are all maxed out, typically using perception based gear. NGD has been hypothesized to be a perception based event as well.

Comment: I follow most of these steps (I upgrade medical rooms, that's important), and even on survival it's pretty rare to have a casualty past about 40 dwellers. Usually just a level 1 guy in a training room, or an explorer I forgot about. Deathclaws die in the first room without me using a single stimpack.

Answer (score 0):

There are two* things  you can do to reduce the severity of incidents.

First, know that incidents are based on the level of your Dwellers. If everyone is level 50, you'll have much harder incidents than if you've got a bunch of level 1s. You may notice that incidents seem to get easier after a rash of pregnancies ... this is why.

Second, you can build in a checkerboard pattern. Disasters won't spread diagonally so you can just evacuate a room and it'll go away after 15 seconds.

*There a few other things which I'll edit in later but above are the big ones.

Comment: Ouch. So basically, don't grow, and don't utilize my space well. I'm pretty well invested in a maxed out vault, in all respects, so I think I'll just start grinding harder for better weapons and such. Luckily I have seven floors worth of dwellers about to come out of training with full stats. Ought to be a windfall.

Answer (score 0):

Im playing survial mode on the steam version, got 55x lvl 25 dwellers with 7+ damage guns and 8+ strength/perception/agility and all lvl 1 rooms

- long story short : do not upgrade any rooms without being totally aware of the increased risks because it will end you

Death claw raids aside i had my vault under total control, so i upgraded my power,water,food rooms to lvl 2 and literally they could not kill a radscorpion before it would spread to the next room, even in my first power room that had the highest strengh and even some 13+ damage weapons

Ive had my science and medbay rooms at lvl 3 for ages but if i fail a rush on them i would remove the 1 guy i had in there and if its a radscorpion i would usually just wait until it spread to one of my defended rooms but with a 16% and 26% chance of failure this rarely happens and i find i never need to rush out stimpacks more than once or twice since im always floating at 55 capacity

the trick there is that the radscorpion will scale to the room it spreads too so even though its a L3 room that spawned it i can kill it with all my other lvl 1 defended rooms, and ofcouse have your high risk rooms seperate from other rooms so all other incidents aside from radscorpions are easily dodged

the best advise i can give is that you should fail a rush in a defended lvl 1 room to "reset" the incident timer, and if you opened the vault door be sure to trigger another incident asap otherwise the game will probably hit you with death claws instead sometime soon, oh and play on the pc so you easily backup/restore your save with a couple of clicks on your desktop since theres been dozens of times i log and someone dies or deathclaws appear or a radscorion goes on a rampage right as im in the middle of trying to sort my training rooms or send out a quest and everything just goes to hell real fast